# How do I return a string from a uniqueidentifier field using node-tds?

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using nodejs + node-tds to connect to a SqlServer 2008r2 express database.  I'm retrieving an object with a uniqueidentifier and returning the entire object as json.

I can retrieve the row fine, but when I try to serialize the response to json, it comes out funky:

```
{
  "Id": "�<�E�ԃM��\u0000ؚ��J",
  "RealName": "Zachary Yates"
}
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var q = conn.createStatement("select u.Id, u.RealName from [User] u where u.Id = @id;", 
{
    id: { type: "uniqueidentifier" }
});
q.on("row", function(row) 
{
    var user = 
    {
          Id: row.getValue("Id").toString()
        , RealName: row.getValue("RealName")
    };
    res.json(user);
});
q.execute({id: uid});
```

Comment: What's the declared type of the `id` column in your table?

Comment: What happens if you cast it to a string in your SQL?

Comment: @ebohlman that did it, throw an answer up & I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably got some character-encoding mismatch. Try casting `id` to a string in your SQL itself; that should force the right encoding.